# Blazor WASM Core Hosted Net 6 Not Installable if using prerender in server method

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

im trying to use the method to prerender my app while making blazor WASM Core Hosted Net 6. Im following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly

Everything went well without a hiccup. But after doing above method, i cant see install icon on chrome.

My question is, is it true when we prerender blazor WASM, we lost the ability to install it as app like PWA in general.

***EDIT***

I am already done everything that mention in the guide.
Here is my _layout.cshtml on server side, here is my _layout.cshtml looks like

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using CobaNet6CoreHosted.Client
@namespace CobaNet6CoreHosted.Server.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
@*    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CobaServerSideNet6.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />*@
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CobaNet6CoreHosted.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    @*<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>*@
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my service worker is assigned on browser, but i still cant see the install button on chrome.

[image: Service Worker On Chrome Browser]

Comment: Indirectly. To get a PWA you need the service worker file which is loaded by `index.html`. This file is deleted to enable prerendering, so the resources it loaded (CSS, Javascript) needs to be loaded by `_Host.cshtml` or `_Layout.cshtml`. As the guide suggests, you can create a separate Blazor Server app with the settings you want and copy these files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos im already edit my post so you can see my _layout.cshtml. I already put everything on _layout.cshtml

Comment: I don't see a manifest. A PWA isn't installable by default, it needs a manifest file at least. [How to make PWAs installable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs) explains the requirements. When you create a Blazor WASM PWA a default manifest file is created as well. `_Layout.cshtml` needs to link to it